# Incluir um fxml via código por um controller

Tags: javafx, controller

Olá, estou com a seguinte dúvida.
Tenho dois fxml: UserList.fxml e UserProperties.fxml.
E preciso incluir o UserList dentro do UserProperties, mas não pode ser pelo fxml, pois isso não ocorrerá sempre, apenas se certa condição for verdadeira.
Alguém teria alguma ideia de como poderia fazer isso pelo controller?

Obrigada.

Answer (score 0):

Poderia adicionar ambos em um stackpane no fxml mesmo e deixar oculto, só mostrando quando a condição for satisfeita, poderia inclusive usar a propriedade de visibilidade e fazer um bind com essa condição.

Outra forma seria adicionar o fxml a scene ou um panel.

```
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(caminho));
    Pane parent;
    try {
        parent = (Pane) loader.load();
        //adicionar a scene ou pane
        scene.add(parent);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(AplicacaoController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```